# EXPORTHOW::DECLARE and role-like declaration

Tags: raku

I need to have a role with a little bit of special functionality implemented through a `Metamodel` class of mine inheriting from `Metamodel::ParametricRoleHOW`. One way to apply it is by using a trait. But I want a nice syntax sugar like we can do with classes:

```
special Mine {
    ...
}
```

Ok, I add the following into my module:

```
my package EXPORTHOW {
    package DECLARE {
        constant special = My::Metamodel::SpecialRoleHOW;
    }
}
```

and everything runs smoothly... No, it is not:

```
class Foo does Mine {
    ...
}
```

and I end up with:

> `Could not instantiate role 'Mine':`

A very brief inspection of `Actions.nqp` revealed that roles have special handling, but only and only when `role` keyword is used for package declaration. Hence, I conclude that the only way to have the syntax sugar – is to mixin my own rule into the main grammar and simulate the role declaration. Luckily, `package_def` relies upon `$*PKGDECL` and it makes such simulation possible.

Am I right in the conclusion? Or a simpler way exists to achieve the goal?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... You are asking for the syntax to declare a role-like thingie? Because I'm not sure I follow the path from that Mine to your use of EXPORTHOW::DECLARE...

Comment: You got it right. Unfortunately, since asking the question I found the answer and it's: no, this won't work. Roles are handled specially by the grammar. Unfortunately, this is done by checking package keyword, not archetype. So, if a role is declared with something else besides `role` – it won't act properly. On IRC Jonathan confirmed this and said that he would change this behavior when have a chance. I'm working on a slang workaround for this meanwhile.

Comment: you can try and answer it yourself below. Better than still show up as an unanswered question :-)

Comment: Done. Thanks for noting on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requested functionality is not yet possible. But AFAIK, Jonathan Worthington is working on code which would derive a package type from its metaclass. Not sure as to how far is he on this though.

Meanwhile, the desired functionality could be achieved through run time extending of Perl 6 grammar. I have it done for [OO::Plugin](https://modules.perl6.org/dist/OO::Plugin:cpan:VRURG) module.