# Making a custom declarator

Tags: raku

Let's say I use a certain set of boilerplate fairly regularly:

```
class Foo {

  method abc($a: $b, $c, +@d) is pure {
    use Slang::Bar;
    …
  }

  method xyz($a: $b, $c, +@d) is pure {
    use Slang::Bar;
    …
  }

  method blarg($a: $b, $c, +@d) is pure {
    use Slang::Bar;
    …
  }

}
```

I'd rather be able to just say:

```
class Foo is/does Bar {
  bar  abc   { … }
  bar  xyz   { … }
  bar  blarg { … }
}
```

And somewhere in Bar, set up the declaration for bar (or, since class Foo will itself ultimately use its own declarator, it could go somewhere else and doesn't have to be pulled out in a separate Type).  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I get that this is basically asking "How do I HOW?" but I've not seen any real write ups, and the extant modules that use it (Red / Cro) are fairly complex (if beautiful) beasts that are hard to follow at a glance.

Comment: It looks like you want to reuse signatures, right?

Comment: jjmerelo: no, actually ultimate goal is to do a method subclass (registering it with the class if used inside it) and using an entirely different language inside the code block (a regex-like one, in this case)

Comment: jjmerelo: see https://gist.github.com/alabamenhu/2fec7a8f51a24091dc1b104a2ae2f04d for the proposal. I'm a few days away from having a test module to show, but I've got most of the logistics of the Binex working, but for the Raku-like syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### -1. Limitations (only for packages)

The method [EXPORTHOW](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/afff3b0b2ed78b2f146eca63f7e34d4472b3982e/src/Perl6/World.nqp#L991-L1045) calls [.set_how](https://github.com/Raku/nqp/blob/80cc57370013b3f1bf5b1b5b491c5d69bd177ac4/src/QRegex/Cursor.nqp#L317-L319) on current `$?LANG` adding a slang to the latter.
Then it [add_package_declarator](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/afff3b0b2ed78b2f146eca63f7e34d4472b3982e/src/Perl6/World.nqp#L1047-L1087) to the `MAIN` `$?LANG` which adds a `package_declarator` method to its Actions and Grammar. It is, I think, the only "dynamic slang" (in  World.nqp).

If what you want is to overwrite [routine_declarator](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/afff3b0b2ed78b2f146eca63f7e34d4472b3982e/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L2375-L2391). Then you have to write a slang imitating the chain just cited.
If you accept to keep the method keyword and make the automatic signature in the class, say according to the method name, here is a way:

**Note:**  A Package is a container (package, grammar, module, role, knowhow, enum, class, subset). If you put code inside like a method, this gets executed (I'v just tried):

#### 0. Description (EXPORTHOW)

I would use undocumented [EXPORTHOW](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/afff3b0b2ed78b2f146eca63f7e34d4472b3982e/src/Perl6/World.nqp#L991-L1045) and `DECLARE` in a [module](https://docs.raku.org/language/modules) because I did not find a way with [Phaser](https://docs.perl6.org/language/phasers). Apparently it is too late even at BEGIN.

The example I give, is decorating every method in a class (even `BUILDALL`).

#### 1. Lib (`decorator.rakumod`)

```
class DecoratedClassHOW is Metamodel::ClassHOW {
    method add_method(Mu $obj, $name, $code_obj) {
        sub wrapper ($obj, $a, $b) {
            say "Before $name";
            my $res = $code_obj($obj, $a, $b);
            say "After $name";
            return $res;
        }
        my $res = callwith($obj, $name, &wrapper);
        return $res;
    }
}

my module EXPORTHOW {
    package DECLARE {
        constant decorated = DecoratedClassHOW;
    }
}
```

#### 2. Executable

```
use lib '.';
use decorator-lib;

decorated Foo {
  method abc($a, $b) {
      say "In abc: $a:$b";
  }
}

my $f = Foo.new;
$f.abc(1, 2);
```

#### 3. Output

```
Before BUILDALL
After BUILDALL
Before abc
In abc: 1:2
After abc
```

#### 4. Sources

- [Grammar::Debugger](https://github.com/jnthn/grammar-debugger/blob/0375008027c8caa216bd869476ce59ae09b2a702/lib/Grammar/Debugger.pm6#L250-L252): exporting a symbol (grammar) overriding [find_method](https://docs.raku.org/routine/find_method) and [add_method](https://docs.raku.org/routine/add_method)
- And npq's [NQPTraceHOW::trace-on](https://github.com/Raku/nqp/blob/80cc57370013b3f1bf5b1b5b491c5d69bd177ac4/src/how/NQPClassHOW.nqp#L784-L795): Looping with `for $_.HOW.method_table($_)` creating a new hash overwriting the method cache with the (well-named) `nqp::setmethcache`.
- To automatize the signature, play with [.signature](https://docs.raku.org/type/Submethod#(Code)_method_signature)
- Jnthn [article](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2011/12/14/meta-programming-what-why-and-how/) on EXPORTHOW
- [So post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53907123/exporthowdeclare-and-role-like-declaration) on EXPORTHOW impossible with role

Comment: Excellent.  Simple, and straightforward.  Thanks!